# How do I tell if my machine supports "connected standby"?

Tags: windows-8

I know that some Windows 8 machines have a new mode called "connected standby" that replaces the normal sleep mode. How can I tell if my computer supports it?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj248729.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From an elevated prompt:

```
Powercfg /a
```

Comment: Can you expand on this? Explain what the command does, how to get to the Elevated Command Prompt, what to look for, etc?

Comment: The "Elevated Command Prompt" command prompt is when you run the command prompt as an administrator.

Comment: An Elevated Command Prompt isn't necessary in Windows 8.0.

Comment: /AVAILABLESLEEPSTATES, /A
                    Reports the sleep states available on the system.